# igraph vs.select() function for c library version

Tags: c++, python, select, igraph

In the python library of igraph one can search for the ID of a node based on its attributes

```
seqIDs = myGraph.vs.select(attribute1, attribute2)
```

Is there a function like this for the c library version of igraph ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, and it's unlikely that there will be any in the near future - the costs (in development time) far outweigh the benefits, especially since most of the igraph users use one of the higher level interfaces and not interact with the C core directly.

*Disclaimer*: I am one of the authors of igraph.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions how could I implement such a feature ?  I am thinking of implementing a separate Vector that is ordered by attribute1 (index) which stores Structs with the id of the node and the 2nd attribute. Does it make sense ?

Comment: You can start reading here: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/igraph-Attributes.html It is not very difficult, but you need to implement the functions in the igraph attribute handling table. You can look at the `cattributes.c` file to see how the current simple C attribute handler is implemented (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~igraph/igraph/0.6-main/view/head:/src/cattributes.c).